# C#: I cant't access information from a list inside a do-loop

Tags: c#, do-loops

I have a class with a List and I am accessing it in another classes method.  That works fine but when I attempt to use the List in a do-loop I always get a "ArgumentOutOfRangeExcetpion".  I'm really confused why using the List inside a do-loop caused it to be empty or at least that's what I think is happening. If some one could explain to me why this is happening it would be very enlightening and maybe I could figure out how I'm gonna get this to work.

Here is my Method:

```
private void ListToAttributes()
    {
        int count = -1;

        //Finds Attribute starting Line.
        do
        {
            count = count + 1;

        } while (Player.PlayerList[count] != "Attributes;");

        //Adds all Attributes to a list
        List<string> TypeAndAmount = new List<string>();

        do
        {
            TypeAndAmount.Add(Player.PlayerList[count]);
            count = count + 1;
        } while (Player.PlayerList[count] != ".");

        //Sorts by type and adds amount to Player Class


        foreach (string Line in TypeAndAmount)
        {
            string[] Type = Line.Split(' ');

            if (Type[0] == "Mind") { Player.Mind = int.Parse(Type[1]); }
            if (Type[0] == "Body") { Player.Body = int.Parse(Type[1]); }
            if (Type[0] == "Soul") { Player.Soul = int.Parse(Type[1]); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which `do/while` loop causes the Exception?

Comment: Now I am pretty sure it is one of the `if` statements in the `foreach` loop - he is trying to split the string `"Attributes;"` at spaces yielding only one string and accessing the second string with the expression `Type[1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first loop will cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if no item in the list matches the string. In this case you will happily walk past the end of the list. Your second loop has the same issue.

Further I think you have to increment `count` one more time between the two loops - currently you are adding the item `"Attributes;"` to the list `TypeAndAmount`. This will also cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because splitting the string `"Attributes;"` at spaces yields only one string and you are accessing `Type[1]` in your last loop.

I suggest rewriting your code using some LINQ (including the step to skip the item `"Attributes;"`).

```
// Skip everything until we find 'Attributes;'.
var stepOne = Player.PlayerList.SkipWhile(entry => entry != "Attributes;");

// Skip over 'Attributes;'.
var stepTwo = stepOne.Skip(1);

// Take everything until we find '.'.
var stepThree = stepTwo.TakeWhile(entry => entry != ".");

// Stuff everything we selected into a new list.
var typeAndAmount = stepThree.ToList();
```

You can also put everything into one statement - less verbose but harder to debug.

```
var typeAndAmount = Player.PlayerList
                          .SkipWhile(entry => entry != "Attributes;")
                          .Skip(1)
                          .TakeWhile(entry => entry != ".")
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: An interesting solution. Sadly I don't understand it :( I never used the var type. Maybe I could be recommended some literature on the subject of the var type? I've just been rocken logic statements with strings,list, and ints so far.

Comment: `var` is no type, it just tells the compiler to figure out the type for you. If you write `var foo = 42;` `foo` is of type `Int32`. If you write `var foo = "bar";` `foo` is of type `String`. If you write `var foo = null;` the compiler will complain because he is unable to figure out the type. This also works for more complex statements than simple constant assignments.

Comment: In my answer you could just replace the first three `var`s with `IEnumerable<String>`, the last one with `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm revising my answer based on a best guess. When you hit your 2nd do loop, Player.PlayerList[count] will still be equal to "Attributes". You then enter the 2nd loop and add "Attributes" to TypeAndAmount. When you try and Line.Split(' ') on that line, it will only return an array with one item in it. Type[1] will throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

I think if you add count = count +1 before the 2nd do loop, that will fix your problem.

Another clever (I think) way to find your first "Attribute" section, would be to wrap it all in one line:

```
int count = -1;
while (Player.PlayerList[count++] != "Attributes;");
```

The ++ notation is just a quicker way of writing count = count + 1. Hopefully you'll find that useful. :)

Comment: I should have a check using count < Player.PlayerList.count but I can't even access element 0 in the loop. Element 0 is fine outside of the loop though.

Comment: It does assume so. My list comes from a textfile that indeed does have a line with "Attributes;"

Comment: The weird thing is it works fine if I do the same thing with a foreach loop.  I just can't think of how to do all the things I need with foreach loops.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things wrong that could be causing the exception.  In your first loop, you need to check and make sure the array isn't empty, and you need to have a condition to check against the array size, in case "Attributes" isn't there.  Maybe try:

```
if (Player.PlayerList.Length > 0){
  do
  {
    count = count + 1;
  }while (count < Player.PlayerList.Length && Player.PlayerList[count] != "Attributes;");
```

Note that if Attributes isn't found, you should probably throw your own exception.  For the second loop, you need to add similar conditions:

```
if (count < Player.PlayerList.Length){
  do
  {
      TypeAndAmount.Add(Player.PlayerList[count]);
      count = count + 1;
  } while (count < Player.PlayerList.Length && Player.PlayerList[count] != ".");
}
```

Note these will just prevent the exceptions.  If your list isn't laid out the way this method expects, you'll still end up with problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Do loop, you're raising count by 1 and then it gets evaluated. This leads your count to be bigger than the number of elements.

This would work:

```
 while (count < Player.PlayerList.Count && Player.PlayerList[count] != "Attributes;");
```

Comment: I started from -1 so I thought that would fix that.

Comment: No because at the end you are still increasing over the length, don't forget that the list index is 0 based, so if the List.Count is 10 your count will go all the way to 10, but you the range is 0 to 9. 

It will be easy if you just stepped through your code and watch the variable. I assume you're a new programmer, it's a basic skill to practice and one of the most important ones too.